# Disable 'Ask question' for users who are not allowed to ask

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

Would it be better to disable the 'Ask Question' button for those users who do not have permission to ask a question, rather than redirecting to a simple page which is then navigated to question again?

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: We want **good** questions.  If the link is simply hidden, then this would be less likely to happen.  We want people to learn.

Comment: @Zoredache Speak for yourself! Some of us just want adequate answers. Or not-so-bad answers. Or answers that will return our calls. Oh, wait; that's something else...

Comment: I'M LOSING ALL THE GIMMICKS...THANK YOU GUYS..!!

Answer (score 21):

By allowing the user to push the button, and then providing the error message, it becomes a *teaching moment.*

Disabling the button, while semantically more correct, is also more opaque.  Allowing users access to controls, but denying them their use if they are not authorized, is a better way to teach people how the system works.

Comment: Well, we could disable the button and show the reason why next to it. Really the entire "ask question" page could be replaced with a lengthy explanation of why asking a question isn't going to work for that user

Comment: It's probably easier just to push a bit of Javascript out to the existing "Ask a Question" page (which has to check permissions OnClick anyway), rather than render a completely different page (you would have to *preemptively* check for permissions).

Answer (score 10):

If that was the case, people would constantly be asking, "How do I ask questions? Where'd the Ask Question button go?

Comment: And they'd post more questions here, in comments to other posts, etc.

Comment: How do I post comments?

Comment: @BenBrocka To post a comment, you sho... hey... wait a second!